# Instantiate class template from "outside" the class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create and use a template class, like so:

**ClassA.h**

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

template <class T>
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(T value);
    T getValue();

private:
    T value;
};

#endif /* CLASSA_H */
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
#include "ClassA.h"

template<class T>
ClassA<T>::ClassA(T value) : value(value)
{
}

template<class T>
T ClassA<T>::getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Now, to actually use this template class for anything, I have to instantiate the class template with the type(s) I'm going to use, like so:

```
template class ClassA<int>;
```

I'd rather *not* have this instantiation in the class header, since the class is generic and I want to (in principle) use it for any type. So I'm trying to put it in my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "ClassA.h"
template class ClassA<int>;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    ClassA<int> a(1337);
    std::cout << a.getValue() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But now, the compiler gives the following error:

> main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `ClassA::ClassA(int)'

Do I *have* to instantiate the template class in the class header? Or can I instantiate it somewhere else? Can I instantiate it in the `main.cpp` at all? If no, why not?

**EDIT**: The question referred to when marking this as a duplicate states that you *can* use explicit instantiations. Not where, which is what I'm asking here.

Comment: The explicit instantiations of a template need to be in the same translation unit as the definitions of all the member functions.  You can either do this by #including A.cpp in A.h, or you can do it by putting the explicit instantiations in A.cpp.  You can't do it in main.cpp.

Comment: If you want "generic and use for any type", you have to put the definition of the functions in the header.  C++ tried `export` to do what you want, but it turned out not to have any benefits over just including the functions in the header.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBonner! So to conclude; No, I can't explicitly instantiate outside of the class? Or can I?